# Exit value of execvp when testing for the existence of a file. C Language

Tags: c, bash, execvp

I am trying to better understand the `execvp` function.  I have been reading the man pages on it, but understanding has eluded me.

The below code uses a fork to create a child process and a call to `execvp` to simulate a user typing in the following into bash: `test -f fakefile`.  In this case `fakefile` does not exist.  I then use the `WIFEXITED` macro to find how the child process terminated.  The 1 tells me to use the macro `WEXITSTATUS` to get the exit value of the terminated child process.  This results in a 0.  However, my expectation would be a 1.

bash returns 1 for `test -f fakefile`:

```
$ test -f fakefile
$ echo $?
```

I understand that bash itself is not being invoked, but rather the OS.  But I did not think 'test' or '-f' were shell specific operators.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main ()
{
    //Variable to hold process id number
    pid_t spawn;

    int childExit;

    //array of arguments for execvp function.
    char* args[4]= {"test", "-f" "fakefile", NULL};

    //forks here
    spawn=fork();

    //Child process as only the child will have a spawn of 0 when forking.
    if (spawn==0)
    {
        execvp(args[0], args);
    }

    //Parent process is waiting for child.
    //The variable childExit holds value of the child process
    //method of exiting.
    waitpid (spawn, &childExit, 0);

    //If termType is 1 after WIFEXITED MACRO with childExit,
    //then we know to use WEXITSTATUS MACRO to evaluate childExit variable.
    int termType= WIFEXITED(childExit);
    int exitval = WEXITSTATUS(childExit);

    printf("terminationType: %d\n", termType);  //This is 1 as I expect.
    printf("exitValue: %d\n", exitval);         //This is 0.  I expected 1.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nasty typo in:

```
char* args[4]= {"test", "-f" "fakefile", NULL};
#                           ^              
# SHOULD BE:
char* args[4]= {"test", "-f", "fakefile", NULL};
```

There should be a comma between "-f" and "makefile". Without a comma they are concatenated,  effectively executing `test -ffakefile`. When `test` is called with a single argument, it assumes `-n ARGUMENT`, checking the "-ffakefile" is not empty string, always true.